# Can I allow_push on individual repositories using hgweb.config

Tags: security, mercurial, hgweb

In hgweb.config, the allow_push parameter applies to all defined repos defined in the [paths] section.  Is there a way to allow push on one repo but not in another, or would I need to actually create completely separate configurations (and corresponding web apps) per repo then?  (In case it matters, it's on Windows with hgweb hosted in IIS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define individual push rules per repo in repo\.hg\hgrc file like so:

```
[web]
allow_push = *
```

to allow push to everyone
or

```
[web]
allow_push = John
```

to allow push to John only

If you can't find the hgrc file in repo\.hg\ directory, just create it.

Answer (score 1):

For more advanced permission management via web interface You might try RhodeCode project.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RhodeCode